# PHP curl post and return second page information

Tags: php, post, curl, loading

I don't think this can be done, but for anyone up for a challenge give this a go...

I have created a PHP curl script that POSTs variables to a page and returns the source code.

Now here the tricky bit... the page the information it posted to is only processes data and displays a loading screen, once data is processed it then goes onto a their screen to display the results. It is this third page I would like to return. Any ideas?

Current script:

```
extract($_POST);

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://check.domain.co.uk/loading.php';
$fields = array(
        'field1'=>urlencode($field1),
        'field1'=>urlencode($field2),
        'field1'=>urlencode($field2)
    );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Here are examples of the first and second urls (not real):

http://check.domain.co.uk/loading.php

http://check.domain.co.uk/instantaudit.php

Comment: probably you'd just have to follow whatever redirects each interstitial page issues to eventually end up at the results page.

Comment: That was what I first thought, but how do you get curl to hold on for 10 seconds, follow to next url and then return page data?

Comment: curl doesn't do that, your code does: `sleep(10)`.

Comment: But the curl_exec() executes the call and return, so I can see how I can execute the call and return the data 10 seconds later?

Comment: html forms don't post data then sit there for 10 seconds either. Most likely the site simply sets a javascript timer and then tells the browser to go to some other url when the time runs out.

Comment: In this instance the reason for the delay is that it has to compare data from sites and search engines on the net. If I can find out how to call the URL, keep the curl connection open for 10 seconds, and then get tge page data it could work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the past (before Google release public api), developers usually perform such tricks to login & retrieve information from Analytics or Adsense.

You can grab inspiration from an old [PHP Adsense class](http://code.google.com/p/php-adsense-account-library/source/browse/trunk/adsense.php?r=2#70) (see how they repeatedly use curl).

Basically, **the solution is really ugly** and can be broken when the target domain update the html of their pages (since you parse the returned html to grab the link):

- curl the first page with all parameters
- parse the content returned to extract the next url (check `preg_match` call in the `AdSense` class)
- curl the parsed url to retrieve the next data
- and so on until you reach the content you want

I remind you **it can't be a reliable solution in the future** because the finality relies on an external source that can change in the time (and break your process).

Comment: Ooh, that is ugly. Luckily for me the host notifies me when a change is made, so I should be OK. I will take a look, thats for the feedback.